# German counterpart of Reddit

Tags: online-resource

Just about to recap on my German which I have been learning for eight years in my childhood and teenagehood, most of which I happily managed to forget.

All the standard German language courses I have checked are extremely boring, so **the plan is that I will find some social networking website in German to first read then participate in discussions that I have genuine interest in**, that is on the subject other than the language itself :) — check [the German Subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/LANL_German) to see what I mean.

Ideally that would be a site like reddit.com ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit)) but entirely in German. Are there such sites?

*Social news site* might be the best label for what I am looking for.

Similar sites in other countries:

- Spain: meneame.net ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men%C3%A9ame))
- Poland: wykop.pl ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wykop.pl))

Comment: Hello and welcome to [german.se]! I have taken the liberty to reformat your question a little. If you have objections to my edits, you can roll back in [revision history](http://german.stackexchange.com/posts/14835/revisions)

Comment: What's wrong with http://www.reddit.com/r/de/?

Comment: Sooo. To clarify, what you are looking for is not actually reddit-like, but more facebook/twitter-like with a bit of reddit??

Comment: @karoshi and Vogel612: I am looking for a reddit-like clone that 1) is not about German language or Germany(in general) itself as these, while being very interesting topics, were studied thoroughly by me in the past. 2) is written, ideally entirely, in German  3) offers variety of topics 4) will allow me to participate in discussions when I reach that level

Comment: @matcheek so http://www.reddit.com/r/de/ seems exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @karoshi: yes, you're right. I was referring to reddit.com/r/german in my previous comment not to reddit.com/r/de, so the is the closest match to what I requested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Combine that with something that is relevant to your other interests:
Interested in IT => Golem.de
Golem.de + wanting to participate in discussion in german language => http://forum.golem.de/
I'd suggest you find a site that is relevant to your hobbies, favorite sports, etc. and join its forum.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure if there exists a better site for your needs than the German subreddit.
Perhaps you can just like German news pages on Facebook that are related to your interests (sports, politics, whatever). As you will know there are plenty of discussions below Facebook posts, although the quality of the discussion as well as the language are not high quality.
If you need help finding a German Facebook site matching your interests let me know.